# Android: SQL database with default values

Tags: android, sql, database

I need to create a SQL database in an Android app. Here my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(createTable(FeedColumns.TABLE_NAME, FeedColumns.COLUMNS));
    database.execSQL(createTable(FilterColumns.TABLE_NAME, FilterColumns.COLUMNS));
    database.execSQL(createTable(EntryColumns.TABLE_NAME, EntryColumns.COLUMNS));
    database.execSQL(createTable(TaskColumns.TABLE_NAME, TaskColumns.COLUMNS));

private String createTable(String tableName, String[][] columns) {
    if (tableName == null || columns == null || columns.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters for creating table " + tableName);
    } else {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE ");

        stringBuilder.append(tableName);
        stringBuilder.append(" (");
        for (int n = 0, i = columns.length; n < i; n++) {
            if (n > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(", ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append(columns[n][0]).append(' ').append(columns[n][1]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.append(");").toString();
    }
}
```

How can I populate this database at the creation?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "at creation"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to start with a database that is not empty but has some content? You can do that by creating the database you want on your computer and then putting it in the projects assets/ folder. Then you have to copy it to the right place when the app starts.

For that you need. Android [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

> An Android helper class to manage database creation and version
>   management using an application's raw asset files.
>
> This class provides developers with a simple way to ship their Android
>   app with an existing SQLite database (which may be pre-populated with
>   data) and to manage its initial creation and any upgrades required
>   with subsequent version releases.

Of course if you want to write some code, you can do without this library and do your own thing.